# Python BeautifulSoup Referencing Tag with space in XML tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

Apologies for my poorly formatted post and written code, first post! I'm sure this is a simple fix but cannot seem to figure it out.

Question 1: I'm Writing an XML scraper for an Eve Online API. I have a need to iterate on an HTML tag that has a space in it (`type id="X"`) with `*BeautifulSoup*`. I would like to iterate over the *item ID tags* in the XML (2 in this example). I'm not sure if `*Data.iter*` is the right approach or not. I know print Data.buy will find the first  buy tag in the XML and print the children, but cannot find the same method to have it print the first Data.`'type id="x"'`.

Question 2: Any direction on how one would continue the scrape process would be welcome. I was thinking about exporting the buy / sell / all to some sort of storage (was thinking CSV files but not positive) with different storages for the different item IDs and the buy / sell orders.

```
import requests #Used to service API connection
from lxml import html #Used to parse XML
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #Used to read XML table on webpage

ItemTypeID1 = 34
ItemTypeID2 = 35
RegionID = 10000002

Webpage = requests.get('http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=%i&typeid=%i&regionlimit=%i' % (ItemTypeID1, ItemTypeID2, RegionID))
#Check if page is up
if Webpage.status_code == 200:
#Convert webpage to %Data
      Data = BeautifulSoup(Webpage.text, 'lxml')

      #Problem line
      for item in Data.iter('type id='):
           print 'something'
```

http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&typeid=35&regionlimit=10000002

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<evec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
      <marketstat><type id="34">
          <buy><volume>21648183554</volume><avg>5.34</avg><max>5.78</max><min>2.00</min><stddev>0.83</stddev><median>5.52</median><percentile>5.58</percentile></buy>
          <sell><volume>15987043271</volume><avg>6.20</avg><max>15.00</max><min>5.58</min><stddev>1.38</stddev><median>6.00</median><percentile>5.85</percentile></sell>
          <all><volume>37635226825</volume><avg>5.71</avg><max>15.00</max><min>2.00</min><stddev>1.40</stddev><median>5.54</median><percentile>4.16</percentile></all>
        </type><type id="35">
          <buy><volume>4163954948</volume><avg>7.26</avg><max>9.39</max><min>4.02</min><stddev>1.60</stddev><median>6.48</median><percentile>9.24</percentile></buy>
          <sell><volume>10154431073</volume><avg>11.84</avg><max>17.41</max><min>9.00</min><stddev>1.80</stddev><median>10.59</median><percentile>9.46</percentile></sell>
          <all><volume>14318386021</volume><avg>10.51</avg><max>17.41</max><min>4.02</min><stddev>2.21</stddev><median>10.00</median><percentile>5.87</percentile></all>
        </type></marketstat>
     </evec_api>
```

Comment: why are you importing lxml and then not using it?  bs4 is using lxml as the parser so I have no idea why you are using bs4

Comment: Sir, this is my very first python project and i'm going off a lot of googling, reading, learning, etc. I saw an example online that used BS4 so that is all i knew to do, ya know? Posting places like this let other programmers give me insight to the things i can't google - you don't know what you don't know, and i didn't know i could skip BS4 entirely!

Comment: lxml.html is used for parsing html or indeed lxml, lxml.etree is for xml.  Bs4 is very user friendly and a great lib but lxml has full xpath 1.0 and almost if not all css3 selectors http://packages.python.org/cssselect/#supported-selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type id=` is not a tag. The tag name of the element is `type` and `id` is an *attribute* of that element.

```
for item in Data.find_all('type'):
    print item.get('id')
```

For the URL that you reference this code will output:

```
34
35
```

The code simply finds all elements with tag name "type" and displays the `id` attribute of each tag found.

You can access the data contained in the nested `buy` and `sell` tags:

```
for item in Data.find_all('type'):
    print item.get('id')
    volume = item.buy.volume.text
    avg = item.buy.volume.text
    # etc.
```

which shows how to get at the data contained in the volume and avg tags for each item.

---

There is also a JSON API available which might be easier to use, especially when using the `requests` module:

```
import requests

url = 'http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat/json'    # the JSON endpoint
params = {'typeid': (34, 35), 'RegionID': 10000002}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = r.json()
```

This gives you a list of Python dictionaries to work with:

```
for type_ in data:
    print '{}: volume = {}, avg = {}'.format(type_['buy']['forQuery']['types'][0], type_['buy']['volume'], type_['buy']['avg'])
```

```
34: volume = 110242267166, avg = 4.29419161677
35: volume = 40908217125, avg = 6.71507628294
```

although getting the type id back out of the JSON response is a bit awkward compared to XML.

Comment: Is there a direction you could point me to find the sort of hidden items under a data type? Such as: the `.text` part of  `item.buy.volume.text` As I understand it you are sort of walking the XML values using the `.buy.volume` but there is no `text` tag I can see?

Comment: `item.buy.volume` is an instance of a `bs4.element.Tag1` object. `text` is an attribute of that object. It's BeautifulSoup's way of accessing the tag's content as a unicode string, .e.g for <volume>1234</volume> the content is `1234`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues, you seem to be mixing up *bs4* and *lxml* syntax, *iter* is an lxml method, *type* is the node and *id* is an attribute of the node.

Since you are using lxml just forget about bs4 and getting the data is quite simple:

```
from lxml import html  # Used to parse XML

ItemTypeID1 = 34
ItemTypeID2 = 35
RegionID = 10000002

webpage = requests.get('http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=%i&typeid=%i&regionlimit=%i' % (
ItemTypeID1, ItemTypeID2, RegionID))

if webpage.status_code == 200:
    data = html.fromstring(webpage.content)
    for item in data.iter('type'):
        print(item.get("id")) # print node attribute id value.

        buy_dict = {node.tag: node.text for node in item.xpath("buy/*")}
        sell_dict = {node.tag: node.text for node in item.xpath("sell/*")}
        print(buy_dict)
        print(sell_dict)
```

That will give you:

```
34
{'min': '2.00', 'max': '5.81', 'median': '5.54', 'volume': '22518685011', 'percentile': '5.72', 'stddev': '0.80', 'avg': '5.37'}
{'min': '5.57', 'max': '15.00', 'median': '6.00', 'volume': '14953114542', 'percentile': '5.78', 'stddev': '1.38', 'avg': '6.21'}
35
{'min': '4.02', 'max': '9.20', 'median': '6.65', 'volume': '4170891614', 'percentile': '9.20', 'stddev': '1.59', 'avg': '7.25'}
{'min': '8.90', 'max': '17.41', 'median': '10.59', 'volume': '10089810619', 'percentile': '9.44', 'stddev': '1.84', 'avg': '11.83'}
```

Then to write to a csv:

```
import requests  # Used to service API connection
from lxml import html  # Used to parse XML
from csv import DictWriter

ItemTypeID1 = 34
ItemTypeID2 = 35
RegionID = 10000002

webpage = requests.get('http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=%i&typeid=%i&regionlimit=%i' % (
ItemTypeID1, ItemTypeID2, RegionID))

if webpage.status_code == 200:
    with open("data.csv", "w") as f:
        wr = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=["buy/sell", 'volume', 'min', 'max', 'median', 'percentile', 'stddev', 'avg'])
        wr.writeheader()
        data = html.fromstring(webpage.content)
        for item in data.iter('type'):
            buy_dict = {node.tag: node.text for node in item.xpath("buy/*")}
            buy_dict["buy/sell"] = "buy"
            sell_dict = {node.tag: node.text for node in item.xpath("sell/*")}
            sell_dict["buy/sell"] = "sell"
            wr.writerows([buy_dict, sell_dict])
```

Which will give you:

```
buy/sell,volume,min,max,median,percentile,stddev,avg
buy,22518685011,2.00,5.81,5.54,5.72,0.80,5.37
sell,14953114542,5.57,15.00,6.00,5.78,1.38,6.21
buy,4170891614,4.02,9.20,6.65,9.20,1.59,7.25
sell,10089810619,8.90,17.41,10.59,9.44,1.84,11.83
```

Comment: i like this a lot. DictWriter is brand new to me as well as lxml. Do you have any advice on if i wanted to separate my CSV files into separate buy and sell orders for each individual item ID.

Comment: Just create files and DictReaders for buy and sell then write  to the appropriate file using the exact same logic